# Python container import error on k8s but not locally

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py)
```

This error started appearing after a recent deployment to **K8s**. However building the image and running the container locally(Both on Windows and Linux machines) using **docker-compose** produces no errors.

The image **K8s** uses is hosted in **aws ECR**, strangely I am unable to reproduce the error by pulling this image and running it locally. It works exactly as expected. There doesn't seem to be any issue with the image itself.

The code where **jinjasql** is used hasn't changed either.

I am at a loss as to how this is occurring, any ideas would be appreciated.

Python version is 3.8. Kubernetes 1.21.

Comment: You can check this link with a similar error [ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' in Release 1.38.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3661)

Comment: Hi @ConorMcDonald Any updates? What about your k8s environment, is it also in AWS, because images from ECR?

Comment: Hi @AndrewSkorkin , thanks for the interest. Yeah the k8s environment is in EKS. In the end I removed jinjasql entirely which resolved the issue. No idea what was causing it in the first place unfortunately.